# SqlServer Set Serial_No Auto Increment and Decrement

Tags: sql-server

I have field Serial_No which just count serial no of student
i used identity(1,1)
But Problem is that if i delete row/rows it not decrease the Serial_No like

Serial_No     Name      Marks
1            Ehsan        50
3            Nouman       40
9            ejaz         56
10           ali          30
11           saleem       78
15           abdullah      90
....           .....       ....
...          ..          .....

I need Serial_No auto increment but also update after delete and insert row like
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,..........

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use Identity_insert on to insert particular value in table

[set identity_insert on](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221(v=sql.80).aspx)

[Identity_insert on](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188059.aspx)